# ¿Cómo sacar acentos en la consola de Visual Studio Community 2022?

Tags: c++, codificación, acentos

estoy empezando con C++ y no soy capaz de mostrar acentos en la consola de depuración.

Utilizo Visual Studio Community 2022. He probado todo tipo de includes, como por ejemplo este:

```
#include <locale.h>
```

En el main, también he probado con setlocale y diversas opciones, pero nada.

Lo que no quiero es tener que poner los caracteres individualmente como esto (que de hecho, tampoco me funciona):

```
cout <<"Levant\242" <<endl;
```

Quiero que se importe una vez y me sirva para todo el archivo.
No sé porqué no funciona, quizás sea algo del compilador.

Dejo uno de los muchos métodos que he probado (cada uno indica formas ligeramente diferentes):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "Spanish");

    cout << ("ó á");
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué compilador empleas? En un compilador online por ejemplo funciona perfectamente. Otra opción es emplear directamente el valor ASCII que tienen estos "caracteres especiales". En cualquier tabla ASCII puedes ver el valor decimal o hexadecimal que tiene cada caracter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buen día,

Puedes intentar utilizando `<windows.h>`

```
#include <windows.h> 
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;  
int main() 
{  
    SetConsoleCP(1252);          // entrada
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1252);    // salida

    cout << "levantó" << endl;   // muestra levantó
    char palabra[40];   
    cin >> palabra;                 // ingresa levantó
    cout << palabra << endl;        // muestra levantó
}
```

La línea `SetConsoleCP(1252)` cambia la entrada de la consola a "Latin 1 Western Europe"

La línea `SetConsoleOutputCP(1252)` cambia la salida de la consola a "Latin 1 Western Europe"

También podrias intentar con `SetConsole(CP_UTF8)` y `SetConsoleOutput(CP_UTF8)` si `1252` no funciona

Comment: Perfecto. Muchas gracias. Me ha servido.

Comment: Tienes razón, le di upvote pero no marqué el tick. De nuevo muchas gracias :D